# Rule to create a new view when a node is created

Tags: views, rules

I have an event registration site that uses the [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module for its registration forms. There is also an admin section that uses the [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module to export all of the registration details.
The trouble is there is no views field (like there is with [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)) that says get all fields from this registration. 
As the site hosts multiple events throughout the year, it means that I have to create a new view for each event.

Is there a way to use rules to create a new view or (preferably) view display when saving a node of the Event type.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better solution would be to use a single view with a contextual filter here.
I don't have experience with the Entity Registration module but since it's entity based it should have an Registration id contextual parameter which you can give a default from the url.